# Couldn't read files properly using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, filereader

```
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath(strheadlinesid1));

    string line;

    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        Response.Write("<tr>"+"<td>"+ Server.HtmlEncode(line) + "</td>"+"</tr>");
    }
```

I'm using the above code to read a file .But this is only reading .txt files properly(Not reading .doc,docx and .rtf properly).   And Can anybody tell how to read .pdf files in web browser like opening in a adobe reader in a new tab.Thank you

Comment: No, it *wouldn't* read .doc and .docx etc files. Those are binary files, this is just reading plain text. It's not really clear what you mean about PDFs, either...

Comment: Did you expect a few lines of code to be able to read _any_ file format? You best bet might be to point the browser directly to the file URL and hope for the best.

Comment: Ok,thank you I'm asking a way to read PDFs on web browser.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Are you trying to just serve them from ASP.NET? What do you need beyond the normal link to a PDF?

Comment: The above code is working for displaying .txt files.So I'm asking a way for displaying PDF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download a PDF file call this code with your pdf file:  Depending on the user's settings for their browser, it may open in a new tab as you want.

```
public static void DownloadFile(string fname, bool forceDownload)
{
    string path = fname;
    if (fname.StartsWith("~"))
        path = Server.MapPath(fname);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    string type = "";
    // set known types based on file extension  
    if (ext != null)
    {
        switch (ext.ToLower())
        {
            case ".htm":
            case ".html":
                type = "text/HTML";
                break;

            case ".txt":
                type = "text/plain";
                break;

            case ".pdf":
                type = "Application/pdf";
                break;

            case ".doc":
            case ".rtf":
                type = "Application/msword";
                break;

            case ".exe":
                type = "application/octet-stream";
                break;

            case ".zip":
                type = "application/zip";
                break;
        }
    }
    if (forceDownload)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + name);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        Response.ContentType = type;
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's downloading.Is there no way to read on the web browser only.

Comment: Thank you very much,it solved my problem with pdf files.Just see if it is possible for ms-word type files please.

Comment: If you want to do the MIME type for word docs, google mime ms-word and you can modify/add to the switch statement for those extensions.

Comment: what is the use of forceDownload above.

Comment: With forceDownload, you are making a Save As Dialog box open on the user's browser (unless they have that disabled, then it goes automatically to their download directory).  Otherwise it will probably open in their browser if it knows how to.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the pdf file in the browser only by add-in for your browser, downloadable from here:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/331/331025.html

For correct view the files in the browser you should set the mime types for it:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + fileName);
```

More about the Mime types:
http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your approach reads the raw content of the file. Txt-Files display correctly because their content is plain text, doc/rtf/pdf and other formats will require specialized controls to display them properly.